# DataView with combined fields

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I have a `DataView` with columns specified and I would like to take two individual fields and combine them into one field, for example 'Columbus' and 'Ohio' and put them into one field that looks like 'Columbus, Ohio'.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("city") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("state") %> '></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I get an error when I try to do something like:

```
Text='<%# Eval("city") %>' + ', ' + '<%# Eval("state") %>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("city").ToString() + "," + Eval("state").ToString() %> '></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Can a format be provided in the Eval?  For example, setting the date format with something like String.Format("mm/dd/yyyy", Eval("myDate").ToString() ??

Comment: I believe it should be `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",Eval("myDate"))`